# How to configure Spring Boot one to many entity relationship

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

In my rest API, I have `Role` and `RolePrivilege` entities with `@Entity` annotation. There are some columns in each entity. I need to set a one-to-many relationship with these two. One role has many role privileges and one role privilege can only have one role. In my DB script file, I set it as

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `wdc`.`role`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wdc`.`role` (
  `roleId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `roleName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `disabled` INT(1) ZEROFILL NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`roleId`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `wdc`.`rolePrivileges`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wdc`.`rolePrivileges` (
  `privilegeId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `privilegeDescription` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `roleId` INT NULL ,
  `disabled` INT(1) ZEROFILL NULL ,
  `lastModifiedUser` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedDateTime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`privilegeId`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`roleId`)
  REFERENCES `wdc`.`role` (`roleId`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

This creates database fine. I created `Role` entity as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", schema = "wdc", catalog = "")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "roleid", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<RolePrivilege> rolePrivileges;

    public Role(int roleId, String roleName, Integer disabled, RolePrivilege rolePrivileges) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.disabled = disabled;
        this.rolePrivileges = Stream.of(rolePrivileges).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.rolePrivileges.forEach(x -> x.setRoleId(this));
    }
}
```

**RolePrivilege** entity as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roleprivileges", schema = "wdc", catalog = "")
public class RolePrivilege implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "privilegeid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Role role;

    public RolePrivilege(int privilegeId, String privilegeDescription, Integer disabled, String lastModifiedUser, Timestamp lastModifiedDateTime) {
        this.privilegeId = privilegeId;
        this.privilegeDescription = privilegeDescription;
        this.disabled = disabled;
        this.lastModifiedUser = lastModifiedUser;
        this.lastModifiedDateTime = lastModifiedDateTime;
    }
}
```

I used **CrudRepository** interface to save new entries to database.

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Integer> {
}

@Repository
public interface RolePrivilegeRepository extends CrudRepository<RolePrivilege, Integer> {
}
```

This is my service file for add new role privilege,

```
// ---------------------------------
// add new role privilege
// ---------------------------------
public String addRolePrivilege(RolePrivilege rolePrivilege){

     try {
        rolePrivilegesRepository.save(rolePrivilege);
        return "Saved";
    } catch (Exception e){
        return "Failed";
    }
}
```

As last I used **Controller** file as this,

```
// ---------------------------------
// add new role privilege to database
// ---------------------------------
@PostMapping(path = "/")
public @ResponseBody String addRolePrivilege(@RequestBody RolePrivilege rolePrivilege){

 return rolePrivilegesService.addRolePrivilege(rolePrivilege);
}
```

But still when I trying to save new role privilege it saves with out **roleId** in **rolePrivilege** table.

I tried it this way,

```
{
    "privilegeDescription": "add user",
    "role": [
        {
            "roleId": "1",
            "roleName": "user1",
            "disabled": 0
        }
        ],
    "disabled": 0,
    "lastModifiedUser": "1",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-11T17:58:14.361+0000"
}
```

Where do I need to change? Please help me.

When I send request to save new role privilege it returns **saved** but when I check it with mysql workbench, the **roleId** column in emplty.

Comment: What error you receive? Describe your problem better

Comment: I did not receive error and I receive saved as response, but it won't save roleId into database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a raw `@JoinColumn` in `RolePrivilege`, change it, so that the name of the column is configured: `@JoinColumn(name = "roleId")`.

Also you're saving `RolePrivilege`, but the changes are not cascading, change the mapping to:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

P.S.: Prefer `List`s over `Set`s in -to-many mapping for [performance reasons](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-collections-mostefficentinverse).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do not return String(wrap it to class for example to `RolePriviligueResponse` with `String status` as response body), secondly you dont need `@ResponseBody` annotation, your `@PostMapping` annotation already has it, third - dont use `Integer` for ID, better use `Long` type.
And you did not provide the name of `@JoinColumn(name="roleId")`